# Given expectations and variances of random variables check if they can be independent?

Tags: probability, self-study, expected-value, independence

I have the following exercise:

> Knowing that $E[X] = E[Y] = E[Z] = 0$ and $E[X^2] = E[Y^2] = E[Z^2] = 1$. **Random variables $X, Y - X, Z - Y$ are independent.** Can $X, Z$ be independent?

Can someone give me a hint on how to approach this problem?

Comment: Writing $U=Y-X$ and $V=Z-Y,$ you assume $X,U,V$ independent and are asked whether $(X,Z) = (X,X+U+V)$ can be independent. If so, the covariance must be $0$ or undefined (but obviously the latter is not the case).  Is it possible for that covariance to be zero?  (It is possible, actually, but you can rule out "uninteresting" cases by noting $X$ is not constant.)

Comment: @Qwk; The titles: “Given expectations and variances of random variables check if they are independent?” In general conditions about moments of RVs, and no more, are not enough for conclude if them are independent or not. In the text some decisive additional condition are added “Random variables $X$,$Y−X,Z−Y$ are independent” but I suggest you, at least, to underscore this part. Modify the title would be better. Otherwise the title can lead the reader in misunderstands more than help them to focus the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to include the whole exercise there and went with shorter version that indeed is rather misleading, I will change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the listed RVs are independent, their covariances should be $0$. So, $$\operatorname{cov}(X,Y-X)=-\operatorname{var}(X)+\operatorname{cov}(Y,X)=0$$

$$\operatorname{cov}(X,Z-Y)=\operatorname{cov}(X,Z)-\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)=0$$

From the first equation, $\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)=\operatorname{var}(X)=1$. Substituting this into the second equation gives $\operatorname{cov}(X,Z)=1$. If covariance of two RVs is not $0$, they can't be independent.

Comment: Please explain a little more.

Comment: The logic of this answer seems like the inverse of what it needs to be: a correct response to "can $X,Z$ be independent" would either be a proof that they must be -- and no such proof based on moments alone is possible without additional assumptions -- or else an explicit example or derivation of a contradiction.

Comment: I had left the details for the OP because it was a self-study question, but here it is.